# How to determine if only one of twelve checkboxes is checked?

Tags: c#

There are twelve checkboxes on a form, one checkbox for each month in year (Jan throuugh Dec)?   What is the best way to see if only one of the checkboxes is checked, for example Mar?

[image]

Comment: Please include the the code that you have already tried along with any errors.  You need to provide a fully reproducible example of code so that we can help you.

Comment: Please, specify UI: WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, something else?

Comment: For Windows Forms, if only one is allowed consider using 12 RadioButton controls rather than check boxes.

Comment: I agree with Karen Payne, if only ONE should be checked, then use `RadioButtons` or possibly a “single” `ComboBox.`

Comment: Don't link to external images. Include the image in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *WinForms* you can *query* `GroupBox` (let it has name `myGroupBox`), panel on which all the `CheckBox` of interest are, with a help of *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 if (myGroupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(box => box.Checked) == 1) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Where can I learn more about Linq?  It worked btw.